# Django manytomany with extra field - in some cases

Tags: python, django

My db structure looks like this:

```
Person
  name

Group
  name

PersonGroup
  id
  person_id
  group_id

InvitedPersonGroup
  person_group_id
  invited_reason
```

Person and Group has many to many relation through PersonGroup, However sometimes the relation will be unique since those people got an invite, and the relation should be through InvitedPersonGroup.

How can I use `through` by dynamically?

```
    class Group(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, 
through='PersonGroup or InvitedPersonGroup')

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need this. Why can't you just add `invited_reason` to PersonGroup, and allow it to be null?

Comment: why to have an empty column in db for rare cases?

Comment: Why make the structure more complicated than it needs to be? Are you being charged per column?

Comment: I am not. but performance wise - isn't it a problem to have a column that most cases will be empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your use case, it should be OK to keep `invited_reason` with `null` to keep your models simple.

For very complex realtionships, keep in mind that many-to-many relationships can be created manually without a "ManyToManyField", even without a 'through' field, holding many types of relationships between entities:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    pass


class Group(models.Model):
    pass


class Membership(models.Model):  # "PersonGroup"
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='memberships')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='memberships')

    # other fields...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('person', 'group'),  # optional
        )


class Invitation(models.Model):  # "InvitedPersonGroup"
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='invitations')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='invitations')

    # other fields...

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('person', 'group'),  # optional
        )
```

This means any relationship can be customized as needed for its purpose.

Comment: Hi, why should it be ok to have an extra null field?

Comment: Because it is not extra, you are using it :-) the cost is very very low

Comment: So in your suggestion I am not using ManyToMany on person group but creating them manually and saving to db?

Comment: Yes. Each model has its own purpose. You can still use `Person.memberships.create(...)`